# How to have different alignment for nav-link elements in bootstrap 4?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap 4, I have these 3 nav-link elements:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Item1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My question is this: how can I keep Item1 and Item2 left aligned (as they are now), but make Item3 right aligned?

I have created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/11/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `ml-auto` on the last item...

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Item1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/XkfSjbcdDb

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin-left: auto` since that row is a `flex` parent and an auto left margin on a flex child will fill the available space.

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.nav li:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Item1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Trying your code in jsfiddle, I can't get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/14/

Comment: @brinch you're using the older alpha of bootstrap 4 and including bootstrap 3... remove those and include the latest alpha http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/15/